# How to create a 16 bit unsigned integer/unsigned short 2D texture in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures, texture2d, webgl2

I tried create a 16 bit unsigned integer/unsigned short 2D texture in WebGL, but the parameters, although they seem like they fit only lead to error 1282.
Here's what I've tried:

```
let tex = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,
      gl.RGBA16UI,
      8,
      8,
      0,
      gl.RGBA_INTEGER,
      gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
      null
);
console.log(gl.getError()); // this prints out an error
```

I've tried this in an empty p5.js sketch (p5.js is just for setting up WebGL and for its other features and I'm pretty sure that the error is with the parameters rather than any previous code).

I've looked at the official documentation which shows that all of these are indeed valid enums in their corresponding positions excepted for `gl.RGBA_INTEGER` (I had tried `gl.RGBA`, but that also just gave error 1282).

`gl.RGBA_INTEGER` comes from a source that I and many others have found to be generally reliable which is https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html and https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-readpixels.html. These show

`RGBA16UI yes RGBA_INTEGER,UNSIGNED_INT RGBA_INTEGER,UNSIGNED_SHORT`

And yes I've tried both `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` and `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` each with both `gl.RGBA_INTEGER` and with `gl.RGBA`.

I've also tried this with both Chrome and Firefox on decently new versions as well as checked to make sure that these aren't locked behind things like extensions. These are just regular ui16/ushort textures and not floating point textures and appear to be supported with me not having found anything about need some sorta extension for these.

Basically what parameters or changes do I have to make in order to fix error 1282?

Comment: I'm using version WebGL2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combination according to the table on webgl fundamentals works fine in Chrome under Linux for me.

```js
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
const tex = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,
      gl.RGBA16UI,
      8,
      8,
      0,
      gl.RGBA_INTEGER,
      gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,
      null
);
console.log(gl.getError());
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Tried that and originally it didn't work, but after doing some more debugging it looks like the http server I was using was for some reason failing to properly reload the files and had it cached. After I did that this code worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna look into [disabling the cache via devtools](https://www.webinstinct.com/faq/how-to-disable-browser-cache#:~:text=When%20you're%20in%20Google,close%20out%20of%20Developer%20Tools.).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I try using that.

Comment: Btw would u have any idea why when using an UNSIGNED_BYTE texture and a UNSIGNED_SHORT texture, using the sampler2D for the former and usampler2D for the later results in GLSL complaining about sampling the UNSIGNED_BYTE texture with uint sampling and how to fix it? I've also tried just using sampler2D for both, but that complains about sampling the UNSIGNED_SHORT's texture with float sampling.

Comment: You're probably messing up your texture binding and uniform assignments. You'd need to create a new question for that issue though.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check to make sure whether it's a problem with that.

Comment: I looked at it and turns out it was an issue with how p5.js linked the textures. Thanks for the help!

Comment: btw for some reason trying to use a typed array of type Uint16Array seems to throw error 1282 on some browserse, any ideas why and how to fix that? It might just not be supported, but it looks like it is in the docs.